Integer Linear Programming - Dividing n people into m groups of specific sizes
I've recently asked this question about dividing n people into m groups for the specific model I used to solve the assignment problem of dividing the people into groups (boolean variables xij that when equal to 1 mean that person i is together with person j in the group). The model was chosen because it simplified the objective function despite not being the typical solution for such an assignment problem, and thus it is not an option to change it.
In the aforementioned question, an answer was provided using anchors to divide the n people into m groups. Now I am adding another restriction: I want to be able to specify, out of the m groups, the sizes of said groups and the amount of groups of each size. For example:
If n = 68 and m = 14, and I want 2 groups of 6 people, 4 groups of 4 people, and 8 groups of 5 people. At the moment, I know how to make restrictions for the amount of groups, and the minimum and maximum size of each group. Therefore, I imposed the amount of groups to be 2 + 4 + 8 = 14, and the minimum size = 4 and the maximum = 6. However, there are different ways to divide 68 people into 14 groups of sizes between 4 and 6. For example, 12 groups of 5 and 2 groups of 4, which is not the solution I want.
How can I add a restriction to specify the sizes of each group and the frequency of those group sizes? Thanks in advance!

Again, this would be much easier if, as suggested in a comment to the previous question, your variables indicated whether a person was assigned to a specific group rather than whether two people were together.
That said, you can extend the "anchor person" solution I proposed for the previous question. Let $N_g$ be the target size of group $g$ (so $N_1=6, \dots, N_{14}=5$ in your example) and let $N_{max}$ be the largest desired group size minus one (so 5 in your example). For each combination of a person $i$ and a group $g,$ add the following two constraints. $$\sum_{j\neq i}x_{ij} \le (N_g - 1) y_{ig} + N_{max}(1 - y_{ig})$$ $$\sum_{j\neq i}x_{ij} \ge (N_g - 1) y_{ig}$$
If $i$ is the anchor of $g$ $(y_{ig} = 1),$ this says that there must be $N_g -1$ other people in the group. If $i$ is not the anchor of that group $(y_{ig} = 0),$ this just says that the number of other people in whatever group contains $i$ is somewhere between 0 and the maximum group size (minus 1 for $i$ already being counted).

Thanks again for your answer prubin. I will try to implement it tomorrow and mark the question as solved if it works.
